# Excel vba for each loop with if statement and structured references

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change the value in a column of a table based on the value of another column in the same table using structured references. So far I have something like:

```
Sub Test
For Each cell In Worksheets("FNM_DB").Range("DB_SS[Resource_Loc_Type]")
 If cell.Value = "TH" Then
   Worksheets("FNM_DB").Range("DB_SS[Resource]") = Worksheets("FNM_DB").Range("DB_SS[SOURCE_AND_SINK_NAMES]")
  End If
  Next cell
End Sub
```

I know I could do this without the structured reference, but I want the code to be more readable. Is there a way to loop through all the values? I know the @ refers to a specific row, but I don't know how to use it in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is possible to use structured references in VBA, addressing the current row is different. The @ sign refers to the current row, but that syntax only works inside a worksheet cell, not within a VBA.

If you are concerned about readability, I'm not sure the long syntax is helpful at all. My suggestion is to create variables that represent the offset of the table column name from the current column. Something like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim Height As Integer, Width As Integer, Result As Integer
Result = 3
Height = 1
Width = 2

For Each cel In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("SizingTable[Colour]")
    If cel.Value = "red" Then
        cel.Offset(0, Result) = cel.Offset(0, Height) * cel.Offset(0, Width)
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The above statement

> The @ sign refers to the current row, but that syntax only works inside a worksheet cell, not within a VBA.

is **false**.

This **works**:

```
[tblActualsWithFacts[@1c]].Select
```

these **work** too:

```
Range("tblActualsWithFacts[@1c]").Select 

For i = 1 to 12
    Range("tblActualsWithFacts[" & i & " c]").Select
Next i
```

however, the combination of the above techniques i.e. concatenating a structured reference which makes use of "@" does not work, therefore this does **NOT** work

```
For i = 1 to 12
   Range("tblActualsWithFacts[@" & i & " c]").Select
Next i
```